# Pass JWT token as header in Xamarin WebView

Tags: xamarin.forms, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm using Xamarin forms WebView control to display a page that uses Authentication JWT token. I could not find any samples that does this either in Microsoft site or any blogs.

Most closest answer I found is to create a renderer for the control in each platform (iOS and Droid). But I'm not sure on which event I should override the request and the format in which the auth header can be passed. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do either of the suggested solutions in this [Android-specific java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55873797/199364) help point you in a good direction?

Comment: I used Leo's answer and it works. Thank you for your input

Comment: I am glad you got Leo's answer to work! Please mark his answer "Accepted" (green checkmark), so your question will no longer show up in the "open questions" queue that we look at, to know who needs help. Thank you.

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the method below:

For Android:

```
public class FormsWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.WebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
{
    Android.Content.Context _localContext;

    public FormsWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _localContext = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["A-custom-header"] = "a custom value"
        };

        Android.Webkit.WebView webView = Control as Android.Webkit.WebView;

        if (Control == null) {
            webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_localContext);
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }

        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

        webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);

        webView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
        webView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;

        webView.SetWebViewClient(new FormsWebViewClient(headers));
        UrlWebViewSource source = Element.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
        webView.LoadUrl(source.Url, headers);
    }
}

public class FormsWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> headers { get; set; }

    public FormsWebViewClient(Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders)
    {
        headers = requestHeaders;
    }

    public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
    {
        base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loading website...");
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load finished.");
    }

    public override void OnReceivedError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
    {
        base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }
}
```

For ios:

```
public class FormsWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, UIWebView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var webView = Control as UIWebView;

        if (webView == null) {
            webView = new UIWebView();
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }

        webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;

        webView.LoadStarted += (object sender, System.EventArgs evtArgs) => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loading...");
        };

        webView.LoadFinished += (object sender, System.EventArgs evtArgs) => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load finished.");
        };

        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            UrlWebViewSource source = (Xamarin.Forms.UrlWebViewSource)Element.Source;
            var webRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(source.Url));
            var headerKey = new NSString("A-custom-header");
            var headerValue = new NSString("a custom value");
            var dictionary = new NSDictionary(headerKey, headerValue);

            webRequest.Headers = dictionary;

            this.Control.LoadRequest(webRequest);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will try and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I'm using WkWebViewRenderer for iOS and WebViewRenderer for Droid, but used your strategy of creating dictionary key value pairs for authentication and it works. Thank you again.

Comment: Do u have any repo, with a full example of this? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I do not have. I can give you details for any specific code you are looking for